# Discord.js mentioning

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js, mention

```
client.on('message', message => {
     if (message.content === `L!hug`) {
        if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
            return message.reply('you need to tag a user in order to hug them!!');

            const taggeduser = message.mentions.users.first();
        }
        // message goes below!
         message.channel.send(userID + ` you just got a hug  https://tenor.com/view/anime-cuddle-cute-gif-12668750`);
    }
});
```

I have tried a few ideas and I am very new to this library of language (discord.js)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to accomplish?
Since you're not asking a question, it's very hard to figure out what you need help with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `message.mentions.members.first()`

```
client.on('message', message => {
     if (message.content.startsWith('L!hug')) { 
    let targetMember = message.mentions.members.first();
    if(!targetMember) return message.reply('you need to tag a user in order to hug them!!');
        // message goes below!
         message.channel.send(`<@${targetMember.user.id}> you just got a hug  https://tenor.com/view/anime-cuddle-cute-gif-12668750`);
    }
});
```

Comment: this did not work unfortunately is there another way to do this as i did
`
});
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === `L!hug`) {
   let targetMember = message.mentions.members.first();
   if (!targetMember) return message.reply('you need to tag a user in order to hug them!!');
   // message goes below!
   message.channel.send(`<@${targetMember.user.id}> you just got a hug  https://tenor.com/view/anime-cuddle-cute-gif-12668750`);
  }
 });
`

Comment: I didn’t get an error it’s just not doing the mentioning 

Comment: What`s message bot reply when you use it? 
Oh i found an error, you use if message.content === somethink. But with mentions message content will never === somethink.....

Comment: Nothing but when I don’t mention people it say @person you need to mention someone

Comment: Change `if (message.content === 'L!hug') {`  to `if (message.content.startsWith('L!hug')) {`

Comment: ok so it works!!!!! but 
` message.channel.send(`${user} + "you just got a hug  https://tenor.com/view/anime-cuddle-cute-gif-12668750`);`
with the arrow pointing at the { 
 i got this error after i used ` ` those but when i use ' ' it just goes ${user} has gotten a hug

Comment: Sure, because user is not define in my code :) .  You can replace ${user} to ${targetMember.user}

Comment: `message.channel.send(`${targetmember.user} + you just got a hug  https://tenor.com/view/anime-cuddle-cute-gif-12668750`);`

this  is what i got when i did the cmd in discord ;-;
                                        ^

Comment: Just use my code in answer and its will be work. The stackoverflowMardown interferes with the normal formatting of quotation marks in comments

Answer (score 2):

`Discord.js` uses many custom `toString()` and an `User` return his mention.
So if you want to mention an `user` in a message you can do

This :

```js
`<@${user.id}>`
```

But a faster way is this :

```js
`${user}`
```

And you can simply put `user` without any String it works also if the function runs a `.toString()` on your string.

like this :

```js
message.channel.send(user + " has made something");
```

Will mention the user.

> Note :
> It won't work anymore in v13.

Comment: hi @Ayfri 
could you please explain how to use this a bit better (srry im quite new to this)


``` });
client.on('message', message => {
 if (message.content === `L!hug`) {
  let targetMember = message.mentions.members.first();
  if (!targetMember) return message.reply('you need to tag a user in order to hug them!!');
  // message goes below!
  message.channel.send(` ${ user.id } you just got a hug  https://tenor.com/view/anime-cuddle-cute-gif-12668750`);
 }
});```


do you mean to replace the **targetMember** in the message and the cmd or just the message?

Comment: breh use **targetMember** instead of user, the **user** was just for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a command handler like this one
this is how you would make it work

```
module.exports = {
    name: "hug",
    description: "@ someone to hug them through the bot command.",
    nsfw: false,
    execute(message, args){
        const targetmember = message.mentions.members.first()
        if (!targetmember) return message.reply("you need to tag a user in order to hug them.");
        var huggifs = [`${targetmember} Recieved a hug https://imgur.com/r9aU2xv`, `${targetmember} Recieved a hug https://tenor.com/LUqw.gif`, `${targetmember}  Recieved a hug https://media.giphy.com/media/3ZnBrkqoaI2hq/giphy.gif`, `${targetmember} Recieved a hug https://tenor.com/1jRF.gif`, `${targetmember} Recieved a hug https://media.giphy.com/media/lrr9rHuoJOE0w/giphy.gif`]
        var hugrandomform = huggifs[Math.floor(Math.random()*huggifs.length)];
        message.channel.send(hugrandomform).then().catch(console.error);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can use `message.mentions.users.first()`:

```js
let user = message.mentions.users.first(); // As a shortcut to it

// Check if there is actually a mention
if(!user) {
  return message.reply("You need to tag a user in order to hug them!");
}

// If there is a user, do this code
message.channel.send(`${user.toString()}, you just got a hug https://tenor.com/view/anime-cuddle-cute-gif-12668750`);
// user.toString() will convert the user object to a mention
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple version of the code. userID isn't defined, meaning you'd need to use the targetmember. Here, this is how it should be.

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === "L!hug") {
    const targetmember = message.mentions.members.first()
    if (!targetmember) return message.reply("you need to tag a user in order to hug them!!");
    message.channel.send(`${targetmember} you just got a hug https://tenor.com/view/anime-cuddle-cute-gif-12668750`);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to create a mention (note that it will not work in `pre`, as no mention works in it)

```
'<@&' + user_id + '>'
```

Note the @ and &.