# Mention a user with a Discord bot (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm attempting to make a bot on discord.js, but I can't figure out how to mention users. For example:

```
@user#1234 high fived @user#5678
```

A command like that. I've tried looking it up but I can't find anything helpful. Anyone on here know how to make that? I'm a beginner so I don't really know what I'm doing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js mentioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891789/discord-js-mentioning)

Comment: Well it's close. But I tried it and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Use `<@ID>` where `ID` is the member's ID. Since you're using Discord.js, converting a `GuildMember` to a string does that automatically.

Example from the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=toString):

```js
// Logs: Hello from <@123456789012345678>!
console.log(`Hello from ${member}!`);
```